# QT Qtestlib, Unit Test

Tags: c++, unit-testing, qtestlib

If I were to create a unit test for class implementation using QTestlib ( trying to figure it out) how would I do it. (I know unit testing for the simple class below can be done other simple way I trying to understand QTestlib framework and whether its really what I want)

Consider a simple class ( just to make things really clear )

```
//Add.h

class Add {
           public:
           int add (int a , int b);
};


//Add.cpp 

int Add::add(int a, int b)
{
int c=0;
c=a+b;
return c;
}
```

How should I use QTestlib to test this class? Some info would be great.

If this isnt the right way. Let me know. Also some info on automated testing would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtestlib-tutorial.html, it explains step-by-step how to create a test using `QTestLib` in a very accessible way.

For Qt versions >= 5, the official Qt Test tutorial can be found at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtest-tutorial.html.

Comment: I did go through the site earlier my doubt comes from the line:

"QTestLib is designed to ease the writing of unit tests for Qt based applications and libraries"

Since the above class is just plain c++ and not QT..does it mean that I cant use it?

Comment: @MrProg: your class doesn't have to be derived from `QObject` to be used with `QTestLib`, so you can definitely use it, even if the rest of your application isn't based on Qt; nevertheless, in that case, I'd seriouly considering using another testing framework, using Qt for just that purpose seems like overkill.

Comment: @GregS Can you update your answer, please? Your link is broken. Thanks in advance.